# How do I know that picturebox has child controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a little game with **c#**, but there was a problem. I put a `Label` in the `PictureBox`, but I don't know how to tell that there's a `Label` in the `PictureBox`.

```
pbArray[x,y].Controls == label; // ???
```

Comment: `bool hasLabel = pbArray[x,y].Controls.OfType<Label>().Any();` if `label` has `Parent == pictureBox`

Comment: _I put a label in the picturebox_ __Did you?__ Or did you put it __on top__?? PBox is not a __container__, so you can't put other controls in it in the designer!! Test by __moving__ the pbox! Does the Label move with it? To __actually nest__ you need __code__!

Comment: Wow,learn now.think you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's put the question in other words:

> If there's `Any` `Label` **within** the picture box's `Controls`?

We can asnwer it with an easy *Linq*:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 bool hasLabel = pbArray[x,y]
   .Controls
   .OfType<Label>()
   .Any();
```

However, we can put the question in a different way:

> Do we have `Any` `Label` which **overlaps** (i.e. just *painted* over or under the picture box; not necessary within picture box's `Controls`) the picture box?

In this case we have to implement more code:

```
private static bool AreOverlapped(Rectangle left, Rectangle right) {
  //TODO: put relevant code here
}

...

Rectangle boxRect = new Rectangle(
  pbArray[x,y].Parent.PointToScreen(pbArray[x,y].Location),
  pbArray[x,y].Size);

bool hasOverlappedLabel = this
  .Controls        // <- Labels that are directly on the form only  
  .OfType<Label>() 
  .Select(lbl => new Rectangle(
     lbl.Parent.PointToScreen(lbl.Location),
     lbl.Size
   ))
  .Any(rect => AreOverlapped(rect, boxRect));
```